# How to git pull without asking password?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, passwords, git

I have a problem for make a auto pull for a git repository. I explain my situation : i have 2 sever on linux (Debian), one for the repos (dev01) and another one for make documentation with doxygen (dev02). I make a script in bash to run doxygen every day and it's work fine.

The next step is to make some git pull on dev02 every day to pull repos on dev01. I try to make a script but when i make a git pull on dev02, it always ask me for dev01 password like this :

`root@dev02:/repos# git pull
git@dev01's password:`

I search for a solution on net and found something (expect) to make a script :

`#!/usr/bin/env expect
cd /repos/repos_name
set password "git_password"
spawn /usr/bin/git pull
expect "git@dev01's password:"
send "$password\r"`

It runs but do nothing... I found some solutions on web but all i try doesn't works. Maybe with Linux i can do other thing's to resolve it but I just begin on this OS.

How can i resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `git@dev01`, I'm guessing that you are pulling over SSH. Therefore you can use the same methods as for general passwordless SSH – specifically, **public-key authentication**. How to set it up has been described in great detail across many websites and tutorials, but here's the short summary:

1. On the client, create a keypair using `ssh-agent` or PuTTYgen.

   (In this case, `root@dev02` is the client, and `git@dev01` is the server.)
2. Copy the *public* key to the server, into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

   (Copy it from the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file, or the "OpenSSH Public Key" text from PuTTYgen.)
3. Run `ssh -v user@server` and make sure it shows the key being used:

   ```
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/grawity/.ssh/id_global
   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
   ```

Comment: Yes i have already make this method but it still ask me for a password. I have this result when i make ssh -v git@dev01    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password                    git@dev01's password:

Comment: @mestra: that means the server is rejecting the key; did you add it to the right file?

Comment: Thx for help me. I add it to /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys exactly... maybe i have to had to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

Comment: I'm daft : my files was called authorized.keys and not authorized_keys.... so it sure that will not works. Sorry for lost your time, it was just under my eyes since 1 weeks :'(